# Bottom margins for two title pages are not equal

Tags: header-footer, margins, fancyhdr

For thesis it is needed two title pages but in my code page layouts are not equal. Problem is in the bottom of the page. the part of the code is:
It is the cls file.

Update: the problem is with the `\newenvironment` command. When I left only 1 page it is fine. When I try to make 2 or more pages the first page is fine but the rest of pages are not. The top margin is good but the bottom is not(

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{minimovka}[2000/07/21 v1.0 final disser class]
\LoadClass[a4paper]{report}
\RequirePackage{ifthen}
%\RequirePackage{fancy}
%\input{defs.tex}
%\pagestyle{fancy}
%\LoadClass{caption2}
\renewcommand{\normalsize}{\fontsize{12}{18}\selectfont}
\setlength{\topmargin}{-0.62in}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0.38in}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{0.38in}

\setlength{\headheight}{0.4in}
\setlength{\headsep}{0.2in}
\setlength{\footskip}{0.4in}
\setlength{\textwidth}{5.98in} \setlength{\textheight}{9.37in}


\setlength{\parindent}{0.4in}
\newcommand{\affiliation}[2]{\newcommand{\@affiliation}
{\fontsize{16}{19}\begin{center}\bf #1\\ \bf #2\end{center}}}
%\newcommand{\UDK}[1]{\newcommand{\@UDK}{UDK #1}}
%\newcommand{\CODESPEC}[2]{\newcommand{\@CODESPEC}{#1\,-\,#2}}
\newcommand{\Distitle}[1]{\newcommand{\@Distitle}
{\fontsize{14}{14}\begin{center}\bf #1 \end{center}}}
\newcommand{\Subdistitle}[1]{\newcommand{\@Subdistitle}
{\fontsize{12}{12}\begin{center} #1 \end{center}}}
%{\fontsize{14}{28}\begin{center}\bf #1\end{center}}}
\newcommand{\Year}[1]{\newcommand{\@Year}
{\fontsize{12}{12} \bf #1}}
\newcommand{\Disauthor}[1]{\newcommand{\@Disauthor}
{\fontsize{12}{12} \bf #1}}
\newcommand{\Studprogram}[1]{\newcommand{\@Studprogram}
{ #1}}
\newcommand{\Studspec}[1]{\newcommand{\@Studspec}
{ #1}}
\newcommand{\Chair}[1]{\newcommand{\@Chair}
{ #1}}
\newcommand{\Supervisor}[1]{\newcommand{\@Supervisor}
{ #1}}
\newcommand{\Consulter}[1]{\newcommand{\@Consulter}
{ #1}}
\newcommand{\City}[1]{\newcommand{\@City}
{\fontsize{12}{12} \bf #1}}
\newenvironment{front}
{\pagestyle{fancy}\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.0pt}
\setlength{\topmargin}{-0.21in}
\setlength\evensidemargin{-0.21in}
\setlength\oddsidemargin{-0.21in}
\setlength{\textheight}{10.68in}
\setlength{\textwidth}{6.8in}

\setlength{\headheight}{0.0in}
\setlength{\headsep}{0.0in}
\setlength{\topskip}{0.0in}
\setlength{\footskip}{0.0in}
\setlength{\parskip}{0.0in}
}

%defines title page layout
\renewcommand{\maketitle}
{%
    \begin{front}
    %\normalsize
    \@affiliation
    \vspace{2in}
    \@Distitle
    \vspace{1in}
    \@Subdistitle
    \vfill
    \begin{flushleft}
    \@Year\\ \@Disauthor
    \end{flushleft}

    %second page
    \newpage
    \@affiliation
    \vspace{1.5in}
    \@Distitle
    \vspace{1in}
    {\bf \@Subdistitle}
    \vspace{1in}
    {\fontsize {11}{17}
    \begin{flushleft}
    \begin{tabular}{l l}
    Studied program: & \@Studprogram\\
    Studied specialization: & \@Studspec\\
    Chair: & \@Chair\\
    Scientific supervisor: & \@Supervisor\\
    Consulter: & \@Consulter\\
    \end{tabular}
    \end{flushleft}
    }
    \vfill
    \begin{flushleft}
    \@City, \@Year\\ \@Disauthor
    \end{flushleft}
    \pagebreak
    \end{front}}
```

[image]

Comment: include all your preamble please

Comment: anyway I don't understand your problem.. You say that your title pages are different from each others but it is clear since you have different codes to print them...

Comment: I mean \vfill seems to me doesn't work good. At first page \@Year is little bit higher than at the second page

Comment: somehow bottom margins at these two pages are different

Comment: Without the whole preamble and a full [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that), it is hard to figure out what you mean. You could also include the output to see what are the differences you mention. But full MWE would be the best!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, guys.
The problem was sold by using `/package{geometry}`

```
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\geometry{width = 5.91in, height = 9.33in, left = 1.38in, top = 0.98in}
%\def\newcommand\mygeometry{\newgeometry{width = 6in, height = 6in, left = 1.29in, top = 0.99in}}
\newenvironment{front}
{%---title page layouts
\newgeometry{width = 6.69in, height = 10.68in, left = 0.79in, top = 0.79in}
}
{\newgeometry{width = 5.91in, height = 9.33in, left = 1.38in, top = 0.98in}}
\newcommand{\makesecondtitle}
{
\begin{front}1st title page \pagebreak second page 
\end{front}
}
```